# How do I combine the lists in the order I want?

Tags: python, list

How do I combine the lists in the order I want?

I have 3 lists. I want to add the elements of these lists to the new list one by one.

example:
**sample lists I have**

```
list1 = ["a", "b", "z", "k"]
list2 = ["w", "5", "1", "6"]
list3 = ["gt", "ty", "67", "l"]
```

the order i want

```
new_list = [list1,list2,list3,list1,list2,list3,list1,list2,list3] like this
```

or like this

```
new_list = [a,w,gt,b,5,ty]
```

How can I create this list with python

Comment: "zip" and "sum" (with an empty tuple as sum "start" value) can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import itertools

list1 = ["a", "b", "z", "k"]
list2 = ["w", "5", "1", "6"]
list3 = ["gt", "ty", "67", "l"]


print(list(itertools.chain(*zip(list1, list2, list3))))
```

Output: `['a', 'w', 'gt', 'b', '5', 'ty', 'z', '1', '67', 'k', '6', 'l']`

Answer (score 1):

Popping should work for the second list output you want, although it doesn't match up with the first:

```py
new_list = []

while list1 or list2 or list3:
    if list1:
        new_list.append(list1.pop(0))
    if list2:
        new_list.append(list2.pop(0))
    if list3:
        new_list.append(list3.pop(0))
```

Comment: Thank you for the perspective you added

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
newList = []
for x,y,z in zip(list1,list2,list3):
  newList.extend((x,y,z))
```